# Podman unable to read config file

Tags: podman, grafana-loki, promtail

I was as told that podman mimics docker. I am trying to ship some logs via promtail to grafana loki. When I run podman, the config is not getting picked up like I expect.

The documentation for getting started with podman was helpful, https://podman.io/getting-started/

But I failed to located documentation for using podman specifically with promtail.

This is what I tried successfully, via docker:

```
docker run -d --name promtail -v $(pwd):/mnt/config -v $(pwd)/log:/var/log grafana/promtail:2.7.4 -config.file=/mnt/config/promtail-config.yaml
```

Running it via podman failed.

```
podman run -d --name promtail -v $(pwd):/mnt/config -v $(pwd)/log:/var/log  docker.io/grafana/promtail -config.file=/mnt/config/promtail-config.yaml
```

I expected to be able to run the same command with podman as I did with docker.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the podman command was ignoring my config.file flag, and instead was using a default config file.

The [grafana/promtail image layers](https://hub.docker.com/layers/grafana/promtail/main-94725e7/images/sha256-7968acd4c2015b3f87d430c2404c3b6f9c8b4d2da177373d6a2c31f0529addf3?context=explore) specify where the default promtail config file is located:

```
CMD ["-config.file=/etc/promtail/config.yml"]
```

After mounting my `promtail-config.yaml` file from my host machine to that location in the docker.io/grafana/promtail container and running podamn..

```
podman run -d --name promtail -v $(pwd)/promtail-config.yaml:/etc/promtail/config.yml -v $(pwd)/log:/var/log  docker.io/grafana/promtail
```

I am able to validate through the logs that my config file is being used and my logs are being shipped.

```
podman logs promtail
```